# Border Around All Objects NOT Each Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I put a `challenges-border` around all the `Date.current` challenges?

The problem with this first attempt is that the border is placed around each challenge, but I want the border to be placed around all the challenges that are `Date.current`.

### Attempt #1

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <% if challenge.deadline == Date.current %>
    <div class="challenges-border">
      <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

### Attempt #2

I get error `deadline` undefined method

```
<% if @challenges.deadline == Date.current %>
  <div class="challenges-border">
<% end %>

<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
<% end %>

<% if @challenges.deadline == Date.current %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Attempt #3

This doesn't work because I want the challenges to be organized in descending order via deadline, which means `Date.current` challenges could appear in the middle of the list instead of listing them all as `@todays_challenges` at the end.

```
<% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
<% end %>

<div class="challenges-border">
  <% @todays_challenges.each do |challenge| %>
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you can separate your `@challenge` by 2 groups, 1st group with border, the remaining without border:

**Temporary solution**

```
<% current_date = Date.current %>
<% current_challenges = @challenges.select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline == current_date } %>
<% remaining_challenges = @challenges - current_challenges %>

<% current_challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <div class="challenges-border">
    <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% remaining_challenges.each do |challenge| %>
  <%= challenge.deadline %>: <%= challenge.action %>
<% end %>
```

**Refactored solution**

- Separate your `@challenges` in your controller instead
- Move the logic out of view, you may use view helper or view presenter!

Comment: Thanks again Hieu! The problem with this though is that `current_challenges` are positioned at the top and the `remaining_challenges` are positioned at the bottom of the list, which while writing this comment I realized that all I needed to do was create `past_challenges` and `future_challenges` so that `current_challenges` could appear in the middle of the list :) Thank you!